# How to scrape mailto from following page using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, mailto, scrape

i am trying to scrape mailto (href) from a html file, but i am unable to "hit" it.

Any advice is welcome.

```
       <div class="exhibitor-contact">
            <div class="col">
                <h3>
                whatever           </h3>
      <p>
                    MLW <br />            whatever<br />            75008             Paris              - France          </p>
      <p>
                    <a class='inverse-a-span' href='#tel' id='tel' onclick="return xt_click(this,'C', xtn2, xtpage.replace(/\w*$/, 'exhibitor::tel').replace(/^Exhibitors::/, ''), 'A')">Show Phone Number</a><span style='display:none;'>whatever</span><br />                        <a href='mailto:whatever@whatever.com' onclick="return xt_click(this,'C',xtn2, xtpage.replace(/\w*$/, 'exhibitor::email').replace(/^Exhibitors::/, ''), 'A')">Send an Email</a><br />                      </p>
    </div>
          </div>



</section>
```

Code:

```
Set my_data = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("anyclass") 
Set mail = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")(0) ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = mail.href
```

Comment: where is you coding attempt? What isn't working?

Comment: I've made plenty, but i am unable to find any was to target that particular href.

Comment: Add in your current attempt

Comment: 'Set my_data = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("anyclass")
Set mail = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = mail.href

Comment: I am always targeting classes first... but this time, it seems that the href is out of any class

Comment: I am also not particularly skilled in web scraping, this is quite out of place of my usual work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a css attribute = value selector with ^ starts with operator

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector("[href^='mailto:']").href
```